# If/else in Razor View that checks html input value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In Razor, you can do something like:

```
@if (TempData["whatever"] != null)
{
   blah blah
}
```

I want to check, in the if condition, the value of an input, for example:

```
<input id="hey" type="text" value="some text here"/>
@if ((#hey).value == "test")
{
   blah blah
}
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work, it is just to show the intention. Is it possible?

Comment: No it's not. Razor is evaluated **server side**. You can do it with javascript/jquery however.

Comment: Do you use a model in this view?

Comment: No @UğurAldanmaz, I don't use a model. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Yes I have a solution. Do you want to use the input value from controller? If yes, my solution does not work for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you should use a Razor Helper class that create a textbox input and a model class:

Example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)  

 @if (Model.Name == "test")
 {
    <p>What a name.</p>
 }
 else
 {
    <p>Oh a name.</p>
 }
```

But as devqon wrote, you should do it with JavaScript. Example :

```
    function validateForm() {
       var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
       if (x == null || x == "") {
          alert("First name must be filled out");
          return false;
       }
    }
```

Link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: Hmm, could you explain a bit more? Maybe show an example?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using a model though. Do you know alternatives?

Comment: That would be JavaScript, if you're going to validate the input on some form submit then you could do what is describe in this link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp let me know if it helps you.

Comment: You marked this answer but also you said that 'I am not using a model. '. Are you sure that this answer true for your scenario?

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz, as a matter of fact, it doesn't solve my particular case because I'm not using a model. It seems that the answer to my question is "No, I can't check for an input inside a Razor if/else statement": in order to achieve what I need I must use either a model or Javascript. I already got what I needed via Javascript. And this was the only answer really, so...

Comment: Chiapa did you use the link I posted about the JavaScript validation ? If so, let me update the answer.